# How to compress files in a directory without subsequent directories?

Tags: linux, tar

I need to compress files and directories within a specific directory. And when unpacking have only the files and directories, not the subfolders.

tar (GNU tar) 1.28

`tar czvf /opt/files/files.tar.gz /var/www/html/*`

```
Ex:
/var/www/html/1
/var/www/html/2
/var/www/html/3
/var/www/html/4
```

Ok

`tar xzvf files.tar.gz`

```
tree
├── files.tar.gz
└── var
    └── www
        └── html
            ├── 1
            ├── 2
            ├── 3
            ├── 4
```

I would like to only get the files and directories (1,2,3 and 4) within html, without the `var`, `www` and `html` subfolders

Answer (score 1):

Change your cwd before running the command :

```
cd /var/www/html/ && tar czvf /opt/files/files.tar.gz *
```

Comment: Thank you, I got it with the command: 
`tar cfvz /opt/files/files.tar.gz -C /var/www/html/ . `